# What is the opposite of yum provides?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

`yum provides <command>` tells you what package provides, for instance, `/usr/bin/python`.

But how do I find out what commands are provided by a certain package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how do I find out what commands are provided by a certain package?

There is nothing as "commands" in Linux. If you are interested what *files* the package provides, there is `rpm`:

```
rpm -ql package_name
```

And you will find your executables aka "commands" usually under `/usr/bin/` path.

Comment: I'll often do: `rpm -ql somepackage | grep bin/` to get a filtered list of possible binaries (catching /usr/local/bin or /usr/sbin or ...)

Answer (score 1):

In `yum`, the term *"provides"* can refer to either *files* or *features*.  For dependency-tracking, the latter is of greater interest.

*Features* in `yum` (and its successor `dnf`) include

- names listed in `Requires` tags in an RPM spec-file
- dependencies automatically found by `rpmbuild`.

Both of those can be listed for a given package using the `-R` query option, e.g.,

```
rpm -qR ncurses
```

(on Fedora23) gives

```
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libtic.so.5()(64bit)
libtinfo.so.5()(64bit)
ncurses-libs(x86-64) = 5.9-21.20150214.fc23
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to find the pathnames of *programs* (executable files) in a given package, you could use the `--dump` option of `rpm` (not provided or analogous to anything in `yum`, although some use can be made of `repoquery`):

```
    rpm -q --dump ncurses | awk '( $5 ~ /^010.*[1357]{3,3}$/ ) { print $1; }'
```

producing

```
/usr/bin/clear
/usr/bin/infocmp
/usr/bin/tabs
/usr/bin/tic
/usr/bin/toe
/usr/bin/tput
/usr/bin/tset
```

The pattern used here allows for setuid/setgid regular files, and excludes symbolic links (and directories).

For reference:

- [yum(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html) manual page
- [rpm(8)](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html) manual page

Answer (score -3):

Simple google search would have returned this to you:

yum whatprovides [path_to_file]

example

```
yum whatprovides /usr/bin/mogrify
```

Comment: And simply reading my question would have told you that I already know about `provides` ;) I don't *know* what it provides, which is what I want to find out.

Comment: it is not `provides` argument. Please read my answer more carefully. It says `whatprovides` as in, which package provides this file.

Comment: `whatprovides` is alias for `provides`. See the [manual pages](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum)

Comment: The question asked how to get a list of files given a package name, and you've answered how to get a package name given a file name.